# Passing functions as props two levels deep

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Consider the following piece of code

```
class App extends React.Component<{}, IState> {
 public state: IState = {
  todos: TODOS
 }

 private onItemRemove = (item: any) {
  /////
 }

   render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ToDoList
          todos={this.state.todos}
          onItemRemove={() => this.onItemRemove}
        />
      </div>
    );
  } 
}

const ToDoList: React.SFC<IProps> = props => {
  return (
    <ul>
      {props.todos.map((todo: any) => {
        return (
          <ToDoItem
            name={todo.name}
            key={todo.id}
            id={todo.id.toString()}
            onItemRemove={props.onItemRemove}
          />
        );
      })}
    </ul>
  );
}

const ToDoItem: React.SFC<IProps> = props => {
  return (
    <li>
      {props.name}
      <button onClick={() => props.onItemRemove(props.id)}>
        Remove
      </button>
    </li>
  );
};
```

I've heard that this can be achieved with the help of either redux or context, but is it possible to pass down from `App` to `ToDoItem` the `onItemRemove` method without using either redux or context ?

Or maybe there is a more optimal way of achieving this which I might be missing ?

Answer (score 4):

From the official docs: *Don’t use context just to avoid passing props a few levels down. Stick to cases where the same data needs to be accessed in many components at multiple levels.*
https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#when-to-use-context

So your code seems pretty optimal.

Comment: The `ToDoList` component renders and passes props to `ToDoItem` corectly, only the function doesnt trigger.

Comment: In your app component, replace `onItemRemove={() => this.onItemRemove}` with `onItemRemove={this.onItemRemove}`